# Need explanation on the behaviour of "echo" in batch file (windows)

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

My problem is that I can echo what I would like to but not the way I want it to. Nonetheless, depending on how I write/arrange the code, I get echo to behave variously, never the way I want it though. Could someone explain me what is happening and why the result is as it is, it would likely help me to understand how I should change my code to make it right. Here are some solutions (limited to 5) and how it then behaves (loop concerns the echo of the second line):

The elements of the matrix I want to echo are (2 rows, commas split columns)

```
, rim_no , account_no , observation_date , observation_month , start_date , maturity_date , days_past_due , rate , spread 
1, 2517, 1000008332, 20160831, 201608, NA, NA, 0, 17, 0
```

1. What I want

when it reaches this loop, it just exit and close the command window

```
:EchoData
SET _var=""
FOR /L %%H IN (0,1,%_colonne%) DO (
if %%H equ 0 set _var=!_matrice[%_ligneAct%][%%H]!
set _help=!_var!
if %%H gtr 0 set _var=!_help!, !_matrice[%_ligneAct%][%%H]!
)
echo !_var!>>%_fileOut%
```

2. What works but is slow

Now my first try, which is slow as it echoes element/comma/element/comma... till the end of the line before echoing a line feed

```
:EchoData
SET _var=""
FOR /L %%H IN (0,1,%_colonne%) DO (
echo|set /p=!_matrice[%_ligneAct%][%%H]!>>%_fileOut%
if not %%H equ %_colonne% echo|set /p=,>>%_fileOut%
if %%H equ %_colonne% echo.>>%_fileOut% 
)
```

the output looks like

```
, rim_no , account_no , observation_date , observation_month , start_date , maturity_date , days_past_due , rate , spread 
1 , 2517 , 1000008332 , 20160831 , 201608 , NA , NA , 0 , 17 , 0
```

3. Strange way that echoes both what I want and what I do not, and is slow

Another try that does work, echoing the result twice, first row the slow way, second row the quick way

```
:EchoData
SET _var=""
FOR /L %%H IN (0,1,%_colonne%) DO (
if %%H equ 0 set _var=!_matrice[%_ligneAct%][%%H]!
set _help=!_var!
if %%H gtr 0 set _var=!_help!, !_matrice[%_ligneAct%][%%H]!
echo !_var!
echo|set /p=!_matrice[%_ligneAct%][%%H]!>>%_fileOut%
if not %%H equ %_colonne% echo|set /p=,>>%_fileOut%
if %%H equ %_colonne% echo.>>%_fileOut%
)
echo !_var!>>%_fileOut%
```

the output looks like

```
, rim_no , account_no , observation_date , observation_month , start_date , maturity_date , days_past_due , rate , spread 
1 , 2517 , 1000008332 , 20160831 , 201608 , NA , NA , 0 , 17 , 0 
1, 2517, 1000008332, 20160831, 201608, NA, NA, 0, 17, 0
```

4. Strange way 2

Another strange way, echoes row with commas, then twice my second row

```
:EchoData
SET _var=""
FOR /L %%H IN (0,1,%_colonne%) DO (
if %%H equ 0 set _var=!_matrice[%_ligneAct%][%%H]!
set _help=!_var!
if %%H gtr 0 set _var=!_help!, !_matrice[%_ligneAct%][%%H]!
echo !_var!
if not %%H equ %_colonne% echo|set /p=,>>%_fileOut%
if %%H equ %_colonne% echo.>>%_fileOut%
if %%H equ %_colonne% echo|set /p=!_var!>>%_fileOut%
if %%H equ %_colonne% echo.>>%_fileOut%
)
echo !_var!>>%_fileOut%
```

the output looks like

```
, rim_no , account_no , observation_date , observation_month , start_date , maturity_date , days_past_due , rate , spread 
, , , , , , , , , 
1, 2517, 1000008332, 20160831, 201608, NA, NA, 0, 17, 0 
1, 2517, 1000008332, 20160831, 201608, NA, NA, 0, 17, 0
```

5. Modification of strange way 2

When commenting one line, it then just exit the script and do not echo anything...

```
:EchoData
SET _var=""
FOR /L %%H IN (0,1,%_colonne%) DO (
if %%H equ 0 set _var=!_matrice[%_ligneAct%][%%H]!
set _help=!_var!
if %%H gtr 0 set _var=!_help!, !_matrice[%_ligneAct%][%%H]!
echo !_var!
::if not %%H equ %_colonne% echo|set /p=,>>%_fileOut%
if %%H equ %_colonne% echo.>>%_fileOut%
if %%H equ %_colonne% echo|set /p=!_var!>>%_fileOut%
if %%H equ %_colonne% echo.>>%_fileOut%
)
echo !_var!>>%_fileOut% 

Basically, I expected solutions 2,3,4 to behave as they do.
I would expect solutions 1 and 5 to behave differently (do not get what is wrong)...
Especially, I do not get why 3 and 4 do work but not 5 and 1. Is it something to do with the echo| set /p?

One more thing is that when echoing the slow way, element by element, it keeps returning "The system cannot find the drive specified".
```

For clarification purposes, I add the full code here (the input file is the file mentioned above, as a csv in my case):

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::Adress of the input and output files
GOTO InFile
:FalseIN 
ECHO You need to enter a valid location for the source file. 
GOTO InFile
:InFile
ECHO Please enter the location of your file in like C:\Users\VerchieD\Desktop\Command_line\example.csv
SET _fileIn
SET /P _fileIn=Type input: %=%
IF NOT EXIST "%_fileIn%" GOTO FalseIn
ECHO The selected input file to work with is %_fileIn%

:OutFile
echo Please enter the name of your output like C:\Users\VerchieD\Desktop\Command_line\output.csv
SET _fileOut
SET /P _fileOut=Type input: %=%
IF NOT DEFINED "%_fileOut%" set "_fileOut=C:\Users\VerchieD\Desktop\Command_line\Output.csv"
ECHO.>"%_fileOut%"
ECHO The selected output file to work with is %_fileOut%

ECHO stop 1
@PAUSE

SET _countParse=0
SET _countParseBis=0
SET _countNext=0
SET _countNextBis=0
SET _ligneAct=0

SET _ligne=0
SET _colonne=0

CALL :ParseHeader "%_fileIn%"

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
GOTO :eof
::Parse input file header, first element
:ParseHeader
SET /a _countParse+=1
SET _list=%1
SET _list=%_list:"=%
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=, " %%a IN ('TYPE "%_list%"') DO (
set _matrice[%_ligne%][%_colonne%]=%%a
set /a _colonne+=1
if not "%%b"=="" call :ParseHeaderBis "%%b"
)

GOTO :eof
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
GOTO :eof
::Parse input file header, from second element onward
:ParseHeaderBis
SET /a _countParseBis+=1
SET _list=%1
SET _list=%_list:"=%
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=, " %%a IN ("%_list%") DO (
set _matrice[%_ligne%][%_colonne%]=%%a
if not "%%b"=="" set /a _colonne+=1
if not "%%b"=="" if %_ligne% equ 0 call :ParseHeaderBis "%%b"
if "%%b"=="" set /a _ligne+=1
)

@PAUSE
IF %_ligne% gtr 0 GOTO :EchoHeader 

GOTO :eof
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::Echoes one element at a time for now, will be changed
:EchoHeader
FOR /L %%H IN (0,1,%_colonne%) DO (
::echo The column %%H 
::echo variable is !_matrice[0][%%H]!
echo|set /p=!_matrice[0][%%H]!>>%_fileOut%
if not %%H equ %_colonne% echo|set /p=,>>%_fileOut%
if %%H equ %_colonne% echo.>>%_fileOut%
)

@PAUSE

CALL :Next 
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
GOTO :eof
::Parse input file data, from second row onward, get lines
:Next
SET /a _countNext+=1
SET /a _ligneAct=%_ligne%
SET _colonne=0
FOR /F "skip=%_ligne% tokens=* delims=" %%a IN ('type "%_fileIn%"') DO (
if not "%%a"=="" call :NextBis "%%a"
if "%%a"=="" goto :eof
)

GOTO :eof
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
GOTO :eof
::Parse the lines from the input file
:NextBis
SET /a _countNextBis+=1
SET _list=%1
SET _list=%_list:"=%
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=, " %%a IN ("%_list%") DO (
set _matrice[%_ligne%][%_colonne%]=%%a
if not "%%b"==""  set /a _colonne+=1
if not "%%b"==""  if %_ligne% equ %_ligneAct%  call :NextBis "%%b"
if "%%b"==""  set /a _ligne+=1 
 )

 IF %_ligne% gtr %_ligneAct% GOTO :EchoData 

 GOTO :eof
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:EchoData
::SET _var=""
::FOR /L %%G IN (0,1,%_ligneAct%) DO (
::FOR /L %%H IN (0,1,%_colonne%) DO (
    ::echo The row %%G 
    ::echo and column %%H 
    ::echo value is !_matrice[%%G][%%H]!
    ::if %%H equ 0 set _var=!_matrice[%_ligneAct%][%%H]!
    ::set _help=!_var!
    ::if %%H gtr 0 set _var=!_help!, !_matrice[%_ligneAct%][%%H]!
    ::echo|set /p=!_matrice[%_ligneAct%][%%H]!>>%_fileOut%
    ::if not %%H equ %_colonne% echo|set /p=,>>%_fileOut%
    ::if %%H equ %_colonne% echo.>>%_fileOut%
    ::if %%H equ %_colonne% echo|set /p=!_var!>>%_fileOut%
    ::if %%H equ %_colonne% echo.>>%_fileOut%
    ::if %%H==0 (set "_var=!_matrice[%_ligneAct%][%%H]!") else (set "_var=!_var!, !_matrice[%_ligneAct%][%%H]!")
    ::echo !_var!
::)
 ::)

 :: for /l %%c in (0 1 %col%) do (
 ::     if %%c==0 ( set "line=!_M[%%r,%%c]!" ) else ( set "line=!line!, !_M[%%r,%%c]!" )
 :: )
 :: echo !line!

>%_fileOut% (
    ::for /l %%r in (0 1 %row%) do (
        set "line="
        for /l %%c in (0 1 %_colonne%) do (
            if %%c==0 ( set "line=!_matrice[%_ligneAct%][%%c]!" ) else ( set "line=!line!, !_matrice[%_ligneAct%][%%c]!" )
        )
        echo !line!
    ::)
)

::echo !_var!>>%_fileOut%
@PAUSE

CALL :Next

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:eof
@PAUSE
```

Comment: Could you explain what's in %matrice%, %colonne% and %ligneAct% and how you store values in those variables? That would make things a lot clearer.

Comment: Basically, I store my values in a matrix style to make it easier to read and go through. %_matrice%[][] is my matrix I built, %_colonne% is the column I am looking to, %_ligneAct% is the actual row (line) I am looking to. When I echo, I go through the lines: [0][0], [0][1], [0][2]....[0][n]; [1][0], [1][1],[1][2]....[1][n];...;[m][0],[m][1],[m][2]....[m][n]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A test code

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem Populate "matrix" 
    set "row=-1"
    for %%r in (
        "# ,rim_no , account_no , observation_date , observation_month , start_date , maturity_date , days_past_due , rate , spread" 
        "1, 2517, 1000008332, 20160831, 201608, NA, NA, 0, 17, 0"
    ) do (
        set /a "row+=1", "col=-1"
        for %%c in (%%~r) do (
            set /a "col+=1"
            set "_matrice[!row!][!col!]=%%c"
        )
    )

    rem Dump "matrix" to output file
    > "outputFile.txt" (
        for /l %%r in (0 1 %row%) do (
            set "line="
            for /l %%c in (0 1 %col%) do (
                if %%c==0 ( set "line=!_matrice[%%r][%%c]!" ) else ( set "line=!line!, !_matrice[%%r][%%c]!" )
            )
            echo !line!
        )
    )
```

For the why part, the speed problems are originated because every pipe will spawn a `cmd` processes for each of the sides of the pipe. Also, redirecting each of the operations will make the process slower because it will open/write/close the output file for each operation. Just redirect the full process.

You have duplicates in your output because you are echoing the same information more than once, via `set /p` or directly with `echo`

For the case in `5`, you must not comment lines inside blocks of code using `::`, use `rem`

**edited** Code updated to follow (more less than more) the original code

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "inputFile=input.csv"
    set "outputFile=output.csv"

    rem Populate "matrix" 
    set "row=-1"
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%l in ("%inputFile%") do (
        set /a "row+=1", "col=-1"
        set "line=%%l"
        call :splitLine
    )

    rem Dump "matrix" to output file
    > "%outputFile%" (
        for /l %%r in (0 1 %row%) do (
            set "line="
            for /l %%c in (0 1 %col%) do for /f "delims=" %%x in ("!_matrice[%%r][%%c]!") do (
                if %%c==0 ( set "line=%%x" ) else ( set "line=!line!, %%x" )
            )
            echo !line!
        )
    )

    type "%outputFile%"
    goto :eof

:splitLine
    (for /f "tokens=1* delims=, " %%a in ("!line!") do if not "%%a"=="" (
        set /a "col+=1"
        set "_matrice[!row!][!col!]=%%a"
        set "line=%%b"
    )) && goto :splitLine || goto :eof
```

Comment: your  example works fine on a standalone basis. Nonetheless, when replacing my lines with your last lines, it does what I would have expected, it exits the script and closes the window without exporting the data to the file. Your `if %%c==1 ( set "line=!_M[%%r,%%c]!" ) else ( set "line=!line!, !_M[%%r,%%c]!" )` works exactly the same way as my `if %%H equ 0 set _var=!_matrice[%_ligneAct%][%%H]!
set _help=!_var!
if %%H gtr 0 set _var=!_help!, !_matrice[%_ligneAct%][%%H]!` and gives the same results as I had when testing examples 1-5

Comment: @Didifr, I've changed the code to conform your syntax, `_matrice[x][y]` with 0 base indexes. Tested and working. Try it ensuring the correct values for `col` and  `row`

Comment: I do not know, It still does not seem to work. Maybe this would help to see the whole code,  I will edit my question, adding the missing part where I build my matrix and with the modification you made the way I understood it...

Comment: @Didifr, Too much code for the task. See added code. Did you read the `you must not comment lines inside blocks of code using ::`?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this was very useful. The idea to split work for first row and the rest is that in the end I just want to collect some given columns and not all of them, and I do not know how the columns ordering nor how many there are. I want to go through the whole first line, only a subset of the others

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing and lacks multiple details. Although your explanation is ample and have several examples, you never said *what is the output you want*. You have shown how several outputs looks, but you didn't said if one of them is the right one, and if not, what is the problem in each case. In this way, your several code examples are practically useless... Also, your problem is *not* related to "the behaviour of "echo" in batch file".

For this reason, I just shown here an example of the *general method* to read a bi-dimensional matrix from an input file *when the elements are separated by spaces and/or commas* (like in your data example), and output such a matrix to the output file:

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set "_fileIn=input.txt"
set "_fileOut=output.txt"

rem Read the matrice line by line from the input file
SET /A _ligne=0
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%_fileIn%") do (

   rem Separate all fields in this line and store they in the next matrice row
   set /A _ligne+=1, _colonne=0
   for %%b in ( %%a ) do (
      set /A _colonne+=1
      set _matrice[!_ligne!][!_colonne!]=%%b
   )

)

rem Write all matrice lines to the output file
(for /L %%G in (1,1,%_ligne%) do (

   rem Initialize the next output line
   set "_var="

   rem Join to it all elements in this matrice row
   for /L %%H in (1,1,%_colonne%) do set "_var=!_var! , !_matrice[%%G][%%H]!"

   rem Show the line
   echo !_var!

)) > "%_fileOut%"
```

Please, do *not* reply that this code "does not solve your problem". There is no way that I could solve a problem if I don't know what the problem is.

If you analyze the output of this program and identify what are the differences vs. the desired output, perhaps we could fix the code...